# Open a view on tapping an image

Tags: ios, iphone, viewcontroller

I am new to iPhone dev, for building one of my sample app, in the requirement I have to open a new view (possibly a view controller) when user taps on an image. Can anyone help me how to approach it, I am not asking any one to write code, just need an approach how to make things happen and also should I have use gestures for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIButton, set the button's type to "custom" in Interface Builder and choose your image as the background image of the button. Assign an IBAction to the button and make it invisible from your action.

Or,

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage 
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button ];
```

Comment: Thanks Anup for very quick response, this didn't clicked in my mind which is a very cool idea to accomplish my job. Thanks.

Comment: @Anup: I tried your way by providing a custom button having an image on that and is working fine. Now when the user taps to image it loads a new view with the same image which was tapped and then allowing the user to upload a new image from the photo library, so when user select any image from the library it is visible to this view but alongwith the previous image is also displayed (overlapping to it) which i do not want. any suggestion?

Comment: @gahlot.jaggs: are you creating new container-views for each image?

Comment: @anup: let me explain my container views.

Comment: @anup:See there is one view (A) having a button which I made like you suggested, then on image tap it populates to a new view (B),having an image view where the image gets displayed,there is a button to upload the image from photo library, now when user has selected the flow is pumping back to view B and it is showing the image which user selected from library. but along with this it is showing the previous image also which came from view A, (it's like one over the other). It may very easy but I am java guy and new to this iPhone era so you could understand where I am doing mistake.

Comment: *FYI I am not an ios developer still trying to solve :p* I can say, for each IBAction a new B is created. You can check if B is already there, show the image on B's imageview.

Comment: @anup: i dont know how to check this if B is already there and ... but for my app i m using storyboard where A is having a segue going to B and by tapping an image on A i am moving to B. For back-&-forth content handling I am using a delegates. the only problem as of now i am getting is, in B after uploading image from library it is still showing the previous image in B's imageview IBOutlet, with new image overlapping on it. I hope got my app structure little bit.

Comment: two images on a imageview can't be shown, so it is certain you are getting two imageviews. Try by making the imageView as weak. it still it doesn't work, in B do somthing as `if (imageview !=nil){ imageview=nil; imageview=alloc+init}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27265/discussion-between-gahlot-jaggs-and-anoop-vaidya)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image, and have the `IBAction` for that gesture recognizer to do a `performSegueWithIdentifier:` call.

You can add a new segue to use by control-dragging in the storyboard from the view controller with the image to the view controller you want to present.

EDIT: Actually, scratch that. You can make the segue even more simply by just control-dragging from the `UITapGestureRecognizer` (found in the "Document Outline"; the little arrow in the bottom left of the storyboard) to the destination view controller. No need for the `IBAction` or `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy I am trying out this one and the below answer from Anup as well, for this I think I will learn new thing (i.e. Gestures which I am ignoring till now), will update the comment after completion.